# Is there a Polymer equivalent to Angular's "ng-disabled"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

Is there a way in Polymer to disable an element based on a condition using a construct like Angular's `ng-disabled`?

For example, in Angular, I can say:

```
Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

And the button will automatically enable/disable based on whether or not the checkbox is checked.

Is there a similar way to accomplish this in Polymer (without Angular)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Polymer you can use the following construction:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{isChecked}}"/> Check me to enable textbox
 <input type="text" disabled?="{{!isChecked}}"/>
```

Comment: Note: `checked` is also a boolean attribute so you can use `checked?="{{isChecked}}"`

Comment: Are `disabled?` and `checked?` documented somewhere?